# Magento2 - Add to Cart not working on Catalog page

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I cannot add products to shopping cart after clicking on Add to Cart button.

Go to

> ***http://marsh.wsisites.net/products/lcd-character-displays.html***

Click on View detail and check.

Comment: `wishlist is not defined` see this console error and fix it

Comment: @WaqarAli That is not the issue. I checked

Comment: http://marsh.wsisites.net/products/lcd-character-displays.html Clicked on view details and add to cart. Worked without issues

Comment: Yes. it is working now. The issue was because of the wishlist module.. i have disabled it for now. The problem will again exist if i enable it again. How to solve the wishlist module issue.

Comment: happy coding ...